# How to store mongodb data in Datadisk in Azure VM

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-rm-template

I want do the following

- Create a VM
- Install Mongo
- Store Mongo DB data in Data disk
- Delete the VM which excludes the Data disk
- Then create a VM and use the above existing Data disk

My goal is goal create and delete the Azure VM, but re-use the single data disk.

How can I achieve it using ARM template?

Comment: I know how to create a VM using ARM template. But I don't know how to play around with data disk for storage and re-use.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is right, on your scenario, you should use Azure Custom Script Extension to do this(Install Mongodb and change Mongodb data path).

You could check this [question:How to change the location that MongoDB uses to store its data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257714/how-to-change-the-location-that-mongodb-uses-to-store-its-data).

You need write a script and test it on your VM and then use template to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

hi i think you can buy a extra disk and link it to the vm it and while removing the vm detatch it and you can attach to which ever vm you want it on later please let me know if that is what you wanted.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview